# Score and win display functions not working for memory game

Tags: javascript

I made a memory game following a tutorial and the score display and win message display have stopped working. It's done in bare bones basic JavaScript, I've tried moving the displays inside of the match checking function or leaving it global and neither are producing results.

There are no error or bugs recognized by the system and I've gone back over every section 5 times by now.

```js
const cardArray = [
{
    name: 'fries',
    Img: 'images/fries.png',
},
{
    name: 'donut',
    Img: 'images/donut.png',
},
{
    name: 'hamburger',
    Img: 'images/hamburger.png',
},
{
    name: 'ramen',
    Img: 'images/ramen.png',
},
{
    name: 'pizza',
    Img: 'images/pizza.png',
},
{
    name: 'honey',
    Img: 'images/honey.png',
},
{
    name: 'meat',
    Img: 'images/meat.png',
},
{
    name: 'fries',
    Img: 'images/fries.png',
},
{
    name: 'donut',
    Img: 'images/donut.png',
},
{
    name: 'hamburger',
    Img: 'images/hamburger.png',
},
{
    name: 'ramen',
    Img: 'images/ramen.png',
},
{
    name: 'pizza',
    Img: 'images/pizza.png',
},
{
    name: 'honey',
    Img: 'images/honey.png',
},
{
    name: 'meat',
    Img: 'images/meat.png',
},

]

cardArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())


const gridDisplay = document.getElementById('grid')
const resultDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('#result')
let cardChosen = []
let cardChosenIds = []
const cardsWon = []

//console.log(gridDisplay)

function createBoard() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement('img')
    card.setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
    card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
    card.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
    gridDisplay.appendChild(card)
    //console.log(card, i)
  }
}

createBoard()

function checkMatch() {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('img')
  const optionOneId = cardChosenIds[0]
  const optionTwoId = cardChosenIds[1]

  console.log('check for match')
  if (optionOneId == optionTwoId) {
    alert('You have clicked the same image!')
    cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
    cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
  }

  if (cardChosen[0] == cardChosen[1]) {
    alert('you found a match!')
    cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png')
    cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/white.png')
    cards[optionOneId].removeEventListener('click', flipCard)
    cards[optionTwoId].removeEventListener('click', flipCard)
    cardsWon.push(cardChosen)

  } else {
    cards[optionOneId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
    cards[optionTwoId].setAttribute('src', 'images/blank.png')
    alert('Sorry try again!')
  }

  cardChosen = []
  cardChosenIds = []
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = cardsWon.length
  if (cardsWon.length == cardArray.length / 2) {
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = 'Congratulations you found them all!'
  }
}


function flipCard() {
  const cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id')
  cardChosen.push(cardArray[cardId].name)
  cardChosenIds.push(cardId)
  this.setAttribute('src', cardArray[cardId].Img)
  if (cardChosen.length === 2) {
    setTimeout(checkMatch, 500)
  }
}
```

{
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 89,
"colno": 17
}

Comment: Please edit your code (now a snippet) so that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens? What used to happen before it stopped working, what should happen, and what does happen

Comment: Yes sorry! a number of the pairs found would show next to the score h3. and then once you found them all, the number score would change to ' you found them all!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem might be in this line of code

```
const resultDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('#result');
```

You are using querySelectorAll, which would return list of nodes and not a single element on your page. Later you are trying to set innerHTML for it and that is not possible for NodeList.

Change querySelectorAll to querySelector and it should work

Comment: this fixed it thank you. do you think I would in the long run be better off just using getelementby (id or class)? or is it just situational.